# Migrated sites don't allow edits

Tags: 2013, migration, content-editor-web-part

We've migrated all of our sites to SP 2013, but now many of them (still with the 2010 UI) don't allow editing to pages. If you click "Edit this Page" it blinks, but you can't edit the content.

Is there a way to fix this besides re-creating the websites from scratch?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It ended up being that someone had the page checked out. Once the page was checked in, it could be edited as normally.

Answer (score 0):

This is a very common behavior after the upgrade process is completed.

First of all, **upgrade the UI or Visual Upgrade**. this will fix all the master pages and other look and feel aspects to the newer version.

Check whether the site is in locked state or not, this can be done via power shell or STSADM command prompt. [Reference Link](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/Cc263238.aspx)

Also, Finally **make sure that you are the site collection owner or primary/secondary admins for making changes.**